# Angular controller definition - undefined is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular but am having issues setting up my first application.

I have the following code in my app.js:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('DiagsDashboard', ['DiagsDashboard.filters', 'DiagsDashboard.services', 'DiagsDashboard.directives', 'DiagsDashboard.controllers']);
```

And controller.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('DiagsDashboard.controllers', [])
   .controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {

       scope.refreshButtonClicked = function () {
           console.log("clicked!");
       }
   }])
```

Yet when I put a break-point on angular.module, the controller function is not defined.

**Markup (MVC razor):**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAngular.cshtml";
}

<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="EventCtrl">
        <button ng-click="refreshButtonClicked">Refresh</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which produces the below HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="DiagsDashboard">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
    </ul>





<div ng-controller="EventCtrl">
    <button ng-click="refreshButtonClicked()">Refresh</button>
</div>



    <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

    <script src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/directives.js"></script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"9f508d482b7a4ca2aca44a79b147fcec"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:13686/72a9c7832dd448f9b586b7c0f340112b/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome the developer console shows the following:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function controllers.js:4
Error: Argument 'EventCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
    at assertArg (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:954:17)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:962:3)
    at http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:4699:9
    at http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:4306:17
    at forEach (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:128:18)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:4285:11)
    at linkingFn (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:4002:14)
    at linkingFn (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:4005:12)
    at linkingFn (http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:4005:12)
    at http://localhost:63599/diagsdashboard/lib/angular/angular.js:3905:24
```

Comment: Could you please add your markup as well?

Comment: Added markup and made suggested improvements by benek. Still no luck, the controller function is still undefined.

Comment: try to set your ng-app to your module name

Comment: Updated to include the name of the app.

Comment: shouldn't that be `ng-click="refreshButtonClicked()"` with `()` ?

Comment: Yes, update also made.

Comment: what do you mean with " break-point on angular.module," ? check first if the console outputs the "clicked" message

Comment: @Eduard, I'm new to Angular so you probably know better than I do, but surely referencing .controllers off the module should not be undefined. Thats why I put a breakpoint there, to see if controllers is a tangible function, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all help.  However I think the issue is that the angular NuGet package

**Install-Package AngularJsSeed**

installs an early version of angular. If anyone can tell me why an early version would not get a simple app working I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things :

1/

'])' is missing :

```
.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.RefreshButtonClicked = function () {
      console.log("clicked!");
  }

 }])
```

2 / I suggest you to use an text editor like "Sublime Text" that completes () and [] for you.

3/ For your understanding, you can write :

```
.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', function (toto) {

  toto.refreshButtonClicked = function () {
      console.log("clicked!");
  }

 }])
```

Angular will only consider the order of the parameters in the function, not the name.

4/ The syntax function($scope) is not minification safe. ['$scope', function(scope)] is minification safe.

5/ Convention code : "refreshButtonClicked" with first letter in lower case for function/method.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the improvements.